# I get a rectangle behind a QPushButton

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I'm new to QT. I used following code to add a button in to a QGraphicScene

```
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;

QPushButton *btnuser = new QPushButton();

btnuser->resize(32, 32);
btnuser->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(50, 50),QSize(32, 32)));

btnuser->setText("1");
btnuser->setAccessibleName("1");
connect(btnuser, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( on_btnProcess_clicked() ) );

scene->addWidget(btnuser);
```

But in the output there is a rectangle behind the button. How can I remove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting minimum width and height.

```
QPushButton *btnuser = new QPushButton();
btnuser->setMinimumHeight(20);
btnuser->setMinimumWidth(20);
```

Then I set the same width and height for the button in setGeometry method

```
btnuser->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(pointx,pointy),QSize(20, 20)));
```